# Alt Gr key no longer a level 3 shift ater upgrating to 21.10

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I recently upgraded to 21.10. During upgrade the system asked me which key I wanted to use for latin character input. I answered <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>. However I’m an Icelandic keyboard user and use that key for a third level shift. E.g. to type `@` I used to be able to type <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>. Now I’m not longer able to, it just types `q`. In fact pressing <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> seems to switch over to the English keyboard. I don’t want this behavior as <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> already does this.

[image: Screenshot of the keyboard setting]

I tried going to the Keyboard settings and under “Alternate Character Key” set it to “None”. This disables the temporary english keyboard but typing <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> now has no effect at all. In fact it functions as a simple <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

If I go looks at the keyboard layout, it says that the key is a level 3 shift, however I can’t figure out how to set it back to being an actual level 3 shift like it was before I upgraded to 21.10 (in the meantime I’ve remapped my <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to level 3 shift).

[image: The keyboard layout]

Here is the output of `cat /etc/default/keyboard`:

```
$ cat /etc/default/keyboard 
XKBLAYOUT="is,us"
XKBVARIANT="runarberg,"
BACKSPACE="guess"
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBOPTIONS="grp:toggle,grp_led:scroll"
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and show us the output from this terminal command: `cat /etc/default/keyboard`

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Sure, edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Gnome Tweaks, "Keyboard & mouse", "Additional Layout Options", "Right Alt (while pressed)" will be checked according to the behaviour you describe. Uncheck it to revert to the default behaviour as defined in your keyboard layout. Install Gnome Tweaks if needed – it is not installed by default.

Comment: I think it's also advisable to make the equivalent change in `/etc/default/keyboard` or else the undesired setting may re-appear.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson not as long as Gnome Shell is used, although changing it "deeper" in the system indeed will transfer the change to any desktop or window manager you may want to install in the future. Changing `/etc/default/keyboard` requires root permissions and editing a system file, whereas current answer allows to apply the setting as a user.

Comment: My experience is that if the `xkb-options` dconf key has an empty value, it imports whatever is in `XKBOPTIONS` in `/etc/default/keyboard`. Hence my advice.

Comment: Thanks. This did exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the steps described in [vanadium](https://askubuntu.com/users/558158/vanadium)'s answer, I would suggest that you open the `/etc/default/keyboard` file for editing and replace this line:

```
XKBOPTIONS="grp:toggle,grp_led:scroll"
```

with

```
XKBOPTIONS="grp_led:scroll"
```

That should prevent you from the risk that the problem re-appears.