# Ctrl button switches keyboard layout after upgrading to Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: upgrade, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I've upgraded my Ubuntu 21.04 to 21.10. I remember responding that I want to use Control to switch languages. But then I realised that it's not very convenient. The problem is that I can't turn it off. Keyboard configuration is showing that the switch layout shortcut is different (Command + Space). Where can I fix it?

Comment: This seems to be exactly the same problem as described in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1371210/alt-gr-key-no-longer-a-level-3-shift-ater-upgrating-to-21-10). I asked for additional info there, and that question applies to you as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Gnome Tweaks, turn off that assignment to change to another keyboard layout. You will find the setting under "Switching to another layout" in the "Additional Layout Options" dialog ("Keyboard & Mouse" tab, button "Additional Layout Options"). Install Gnome Tweaks if you do not yet have it installed.

Comment: I think it's also advisable to make the equivalent change in `/etc/default/keyboard` or else the undesired setting may re-appear.

Comment: Great! Worked for me!